# Threads and Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Im not clear with Threads and multithreading. How do they work, do they share the same call stack, and if yes how they can work and kind of parrarel. Can somebody please explain in detail how they work under the hook, and what is this parrarelism in multithreading, im still not getting it. When they share the call stack, and how effectively multithreading works.

Comment: I can't help but feel like you're worrying about the wood and not seeing the trees. Have you tried using them? What were the practical problems you encountered?

Comment: You mean how the JVM does it ?

Comment: This is a complex topic and it's easy to get lost. Here's how I would approach it:
- read and understand the basic idea (your favorite documentation/example site)
- write some code, play with something in a multi threaded way (here you'll most likely hit issues and that is  a good spot to start searching for answers and learning more)
- once you have something running, read more about threads, issues with them and pitfalls
By the time you get here you should have answered your question already.

Check out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html

Answer (score 1):

> How do they work.

It is complicated.  There are whole books on this.

> do they share the same call stack,

No.  Each thread has its own call stack.

> Can somebody please explain in detail how they work under the hook, and what is this parrarelism in multithreading

Seriously, if you don't (yet) understand what parallelism is, you are not (yet) equipped to understand how multithreading works *under the hood*.

I suggest that you start by reading the [Oracle Java tutorial on concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).  Then if you need to understand threads more deeply, buy and read ["Java: Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz et al.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

When you have read ... and understood ... those things, you should be equipped to learn how threads work under the hood.  But the ability to read C and C++ code would also help, since that's what the JVM is implemented in *under the hood*.